# node.js returning on 'data' event

Tags: javascript, node.js

suppose i want to return data on 'data' event of event loop:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var test = function(str){
    stream = fs.createReadStream(str, {
        flags: 'r',
        encoding: 'utf-8',
        fd: null,
        bufferSize: 1
    }),
    line ='';

    stream.on('data', function(char){
        return line += char;
    }); 
    stream.on('end', function(){
        console.log(line.length);
    }); 
}
test("/path/to/file");
```

What is the difference between this and when i write:

```
stream.on('data', function(char){
    line += char;
});
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: on `data` event takes a callback function. it's a sort of observer pattern. it does not matter if the callback returns something as the return value will not be returned to anyone.

Comment: Does it matter if you return a http response (or database response) inside event handler ?